# phpmyadmin login with mod_rewrite rule

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have set up docker infrastructure with LAMP and phpmyadmin installed.
Based on the domains Apache is redirecting request to specific directory what produce an error in phpmyadmin:

> Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.

I think that a problem is cookie path which looks like:

```
Set-Cookie: phpMyAdmin=vp315vnwjucqm7eonefgqukk8; path=/domains/phpmyadmin.xxxx.com/; secure; HttpOnly
```

phpmyadmin is working perfeclty with full path.

My rewrite rule in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ domains/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The Error Message is pretty self-descriptive and the cookie contains the "`HttpOnly`" Character String. "_Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin._"

Comment: Yes. I'm using haproxy with ssl and apache <=> haproxy comunication is over pure http.

Comment: Then again, the Error Message is quite straightforward. It is expecting H.T.T.P.S.

Comment: How to force phpmyadmin to use pure http ?

Comment: Maybe this is the Real Question. Maybe you could change the Title of the Question in order to contain it, so that our Readers get to the point without reading our Comments.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem with adding to config.inc.php

```
$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri'] = 'http://phpmyadmin.xxxxx.com/';
```